# Highcharts - How to deal with separately scrollbar on multi-charts

Tags: highcharts

#### Scenario

I have 2 data source 10/20 records.

- `data.src10.series` and `data.src10.categories`
- `data.src20.series` and `data.src20.categories`

`show_rank_limit` this function will show all rank on left

- When I click `latest top 10` button, it will

  - show 10 rank
  - no scrollbar
  - switch to 10 records datasource `data.src10`
    [image]
- When I click `latest top 20` button, it will

  - show 20 rank
  - with scrollbar
  - switch to 20 records datasource `data.src20`
    [image]
- Both keep 10 rank height.

#### My problem

How to deal with separately on multi-charts.

- When I call `chart1.series[0].setData` it will clear my style and some data, it should not be happened! why?

  [image]
- Did I use `redraw` event? it will cause too many `redraw` when I use scrollbar.

  ```
  redraw: function(event) {
      cfg.common.fun.show_rank_limit(this);
  }
  ```
- When I click `latest top 20` it will keep 10 rank height, but cannot scroll down.
  [image]
- What I found. I put `'AAAAA BBBBB', 'AAAA-BBBBB'` to data, seems it cannot display normally. And it can take html tag. ( eg. `<b></b>`) see above screenshot.

html code

```
<div id="container1" class="container" ...></div>
<br>
<div id="container2" class="container" ...></div>
```

js code

```
show_rank_limit: function(that) {
    $("text.rank").remove();//remove all rank before render
    ...
}

var barchart1 = cfg.common;
barchart1.series = data.src20.series;
barchart1.xAxis.categories = data.src10.categories;
barchart1.title.text = 'barchart 1';

var barchart2 = _.cloneDeep(barchart1);
barchart2.title.text = 'barchart 2';

var chart1 = Highcharts.chart('container1', barchart1);
var chart2 = Highcharts.chart('container2', barchart2);

$('#top10').click(function() {
  chart1.series[0].setData(data.src10.series, false);
  chart1.xAxis[0].setCategories(data.src10.categories, false);
  chart1.xAxis[0].update({
    scrollbar: {
      enabled: false
    }
  });
});

$('#top20').click(function() {
  chart1.series[0].setData(data.src20.series, false);
  chart1.xAxis[0].setCategories(data.src20.categories, false);
  chart1.xAxis[0].update({
    scrollbar: {
      enabled: true
    }
  });
});
```

```

DEMO : https://jsfiddle.net/puff0211/6rxd31xk/

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Check documentation about [setData](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series.html#setData). It think you are confused with series.
setData updates data inside series, and you are passing series not data.

update with `chart1.series[0].setData(data.src10.series[0].data, false);` and
`chart1.series[0].setData(data.src20.series[0].data, false);`

```
$('#top10').click(function() {
  chart1.series[0].setData(data.src10.series[0].data, false);
  chart1.xAxis[0].setCategories(data.src10.categories, false);
  chart1.xAxis[0].update({
    scrollbar: {
      enabled: false
    }
  });
});

$('#top20').click(function() {
  chart1.series[0].setData(data.src20.series[0].data, false);
  chart1.xAxis[0].setCategories(data.src20.categories, false);
  chart1.xAxis[0].update({
    scrollbar: {
      enabled: true
    }
  });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qj1jovgo/) demo

Comment: check https://jsfiddle.net/qj1jovgo/1/. here `$('#top20').click(function() {
console.log(data.src20.series[0].data) //check here is problem})`  your data is update. Is this your required behavior

Comment: Yes, this is what I expected. thank you, should I separate the stackoverflow question into new one and close this question?

Comment: Hi still not getting what you want. Do you want to update series data on click of button. This is happening now. But  some how your data`data.src20.series[0].data` is updated. Is data modification required ???

Comment: the problem is Shallow Copy  VS  Deep Copy , see this http://i.imgur.com/abBTAP3.png
I can resolve it use below code.
https://jsfiddle.net/puff0211/qj1jovgo/2/
var data10 = _.cloneDeep(data.src10.series[0].data);
var data20 = _.cloneDeep(data.src20.series[0].data);